# Read csv with headers into a data structure in Octave

Tags: csv, data-structures, file-io, octave, cell-array

I mean to read a data file with one line of headers into a data structure `ds` that has the csv headers as `fieldnames(ds)`.
So for the sample file below I would be able to do `ds.x` or `ds.('x')`, e.g.

But using

```
ds = importdata(ds_fname, delimiterIn = ',', headerlinesIn = 1);
```

I get instead

```
> fieldnames(ds)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = data
  [2,1] = textdata
  [3,1] = colheaders
}

> ds.colheaders
ans =
{
  [1,1] = x
  [1,2] = y1
  [1,3] = y2
}

> ds.data
ans =

      <mydata>
```

**How can I read directly a csv into a data strcture?**
I managed to read the csv into a cell array and then creating the data structure, but I mean to avoid intermediate steps.

---

Sample data file

```
x,y1,y2
0.1,1.0,1.0e-1
4.,21.0,1.0e1
6,-1,1.0e+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pkg load io
C = csv2cell('data.csv');
S = cell2struct( C(2:end,:).', C(1,:) );
```

Comment: No direct csv to strcutrue?
This is what I am currently using (mentioned in the OP, even if the commands were not explicitly listed).

Comment: not that I'm aware of, but there's nothing stopping you from wrapping this into a function